# change scrollTop in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just learn react, and want to achieve a function : 
**both A,B are components, if A scroll, then B scroll**

The following is my code

`<A onScroll="handleScroll"></A>`

```
//what i write now
handleScroll: function(event){
    var target = event.nativeEvent.target;

    //do something to change scrollTop value
    target.scrollTop += 1;

    // it looks the same as not use react
    document.getElementById(B).scrollTop = target.scrollTop;
}
```

but actually I want my code like this

```
//what i want
<A scrollTop={this.props.scrollSeed}></A>
<B scrollTop={this.props.scrollSeed}></B>

//...
handleScroll(){
    this.setState({scrollSeed: ++this.state.scrollSeed})
}
```

it is similar to `input`

```
<input value="this.props.value"/>
<input value="this.props.value"/>
<input ref='c' onChange={handleChange}>

//...
handleChange: function() {
    // enter some code in c and then render in a and b automatically
}
```

In other words, I want some attribute, like `scrollTop`(different
form `<input value={}>` ,because `<A scrollTop={}>` doesn't work) ,is bind with some state, so that I can just use `setState`, and they will update by themselves.

I googled before but can't find the answser. I hope that my poor English won't confuse you.

Answer (score 17):

There are a number of patterns to achieve this. This [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/szchenghuang/x23anmwr/) is what I came up with to get you up and going.

First create a component class which has an oversize element for scroll effect. When dragging the scroll bar, this component calls its `handleScroll` React property to notify its parent component, with the value of `scrollTop`.

```
var Elem = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div ref="elem"
                onScroll={ this.onScroll }
                style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px", overflow: "scroll" }}>
                <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "200%" }}>Hello!</div>
            </div>
        );
    },
    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.refs.elem.scrollTop = this.props.scrollTop;
    },
    onScroll() {
        this.props.handleScroll( this.refs.elem.scrollTop );
    }
});
```

The parent component, aka wrapper, keeps the scroll top value in its state. Its `handleScroll` is passed to the child components as callback. Any scroll on the child elements triggers the callback, sets the state, results in a redraw, and updates the child component.

```
var Wrapper = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            scrollTop: 0
        }
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Elem scrollTop={ this.state.scrollTop } handleScroll={ this.handleScroll } />
                <Elem scrollTop={ this.state.scrollTop } handleScroll={ this.handleScroll } />
            </div>
        );
    },
    handleScroll( scrollTop ) {
        this.setState({ scrollTop });
    }
});
```

And render the wrapper, presuming an existing `<div id="container"></div>`.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Wrapper />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! And I found that there no need to use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode( )`, `this.refs.elem` is enough(and also save 10% usage of my CPU,^_^); Before that, I just try to put my code in `componentWillMount`, but it shoule be `componentDidUpdate`;After all, thanks again;

Comment: @edeity, that's very true; revised.

Comment: `this.refs` is deprecated. use https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs

Answer (score 16):

## 2019's answer

First, the fix:

```
const resetScrollEffect = ({ element }) => {
  element.current.getScrollableNode().children[0].scrollTop = 0
}

const Table = props => {
  const tableRef = useRef(null)
  useEffect(() => resetScrollEffect({ element: tableRef }), [])
  return (
    <Component>
      <FlatList
        ref={someRef}
      />
    </Component>
  )
}
```

Second, a little explanation:

Idk what is your reason why you got here but I have used `flex-direction: column-reverse` for my FlatList (it's a list of elements). And I need this property for `z-index` purposes. However, browsers set their scroll position to the end for such elements (tables, chats, etc.) - this may be useful but I don't need that in my case.

Also, example is shown using [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html), but you can use <s>older</s> more traditional way of defining refs

Comment: I think this is about React Web and your answer applies to React Native. I also wonder how to trigger the effect on click. It seems an effect will be called when loaded and when there's any state or props change.

Comment: Perhaps rename `resetScrollEffect` to `resetScroll` and make the button say `onClick={ .resetScroll({ element: tableRef }) }`?

Comment: @BenjaminAtkin it's a standard to name functions `*Effect` when it's used for `useEffect` in react. But the main line corresponding to the question is this `element.current.getScrollableNode().children[0].scrollTop =` because `element.current.scrollTop = ` in above answer isn't working for me (it was working in some older times)

Comment: Thanks man, must have to login and upvote! It's hard to find solution for hooks. 
`element.current.scrollTop` works perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

this.refs is deprecated. use reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs

```js
import React from 'react';

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.resultsDiv = React.createRef();
  }

  someFunction(){
     this.resultsDiv.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});

     // alternative:
     // this.resultsDiv.current.scrollTop = 0;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.resultsDiv} />
    );
  }
}

export default SomeComponent;
```

Comment: @jimish try `this.resultsDiv.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});`. this may not work because of other issues related to css layout, positioning of div. try using this on some other element which you know is positioned with default css.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an updated version of [Season's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33750570/4794), including a runnable snippet. It uses the recommended method for [creating refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs).

```js
class Editor extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.content = React.createRef();
        this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.content.current.scrollTop = this.props.scrollTop;
    }
    
    handleScroll() {
        this.props.onScroll( this.content.current.scrollTop );
    }

    render() {
        let text = 'a\n\nb\n\nc\n\nd\n\ne\n\nf\n\ng';
        return <textarea
            ref={this.content}
            value={text}
            rows="10"
            cols="30"
            onScroll={this.handleScroll}/>;
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {scrollTop: 0};
        this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
    }

    handleScroll(scrollTop) {
        this.setState({scrollTop: scrollTop});
    }

    render() {
        return <table><tbody>
            <tr><th>Foo</th><th>Bar</th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td><Editor
                    scrollTop={this.state.scrollTop}
                    onScroll={this.handleScroll}/></td>
                <td><Editor
                    scrollTop={this.state.scrollTop}
                    onScroll={this.handleScroll}/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```